# Pynput click is registering as a normal click?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

The idea of my script is to click repeatedly, but only while the mouse is held. However, it doesn't work, and I think it is because when I click with pynput, it stops clicking outside of the boolean flags; this  might not be right though...

Code is:

```
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode, Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button, Listener as MouseListener
import time
import threading

button_to_click = Button.left
button_to_toggle = KeyCode(char="x")
cps = 15


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, button, _cps):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.cps = _cps
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.active = True
        self.mouse = Controller()
        self.is_clicking = False

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.active:
                while self.running:
                    self.is_clicking = True
                    self.mouse.click(self.button)
                    self.is_clicking = False
                    time.sleep(1 / self.cps)


clicker = ClickMouse(button_to_click, cps)
clicker.start()


def on_click(x, y, button_clicked, pressed):
    if not clicker.is_clicking and pressed:
        print("User started clicker")
        clicker.start_clicking()
    elif not clicker.is_clicking:
        print("User ended clicker")
        clicker.stop_clicking()


def on_press(key):
    if key == button_to_toggle:
        clicker.active = not clicker.active


with MouseListener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    with KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Output when holding mouse down is:

```
>>> User started clicker
>>> User ended clicker
>>> User ended clicker
```

It should just say that it has ended once, when I release right click, and terminate the rapid clicking, but instead it does this, and doesn't click repeatedly but rather stops after 1 click
This is what made me think it is pynput's click releasing after the Boolean flags

Any help would be appreciated with this issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, though it's a bit patchy...

Just used a quick time.sleep() following the click but before the boolean flag, and now it works. Not a great clicker though.

Code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import KeyCode, Listener as KeyboardListener
from pynput.mouse import Controller, Button, Listener as MouseListener
import time
import threading

button_to_click = Button.left
button_to_toggle = KeyCode(char="x")
cps = 15


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, button, _cps):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.cps = _cps
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.active = True
        self.mouse = Controller()
        self.is_clicking = False

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        while True:
            while self.active:
                while self.running:
                    self.is_clicking = True
                    self.mouse.click(self.button)
                    time.sleep(0.001)
                    self.is_clicking = False
                    time.sleep(1 / self.cps)


clicker = ClickMouse(button_to_click, cps)
clicker.start()


def on_click(x, y, button_clicked, pressed):
    if clicker.is_clicking:
        return
    if pressed:
        clicker.start_clicking()
    else:
        clicker.stop_clicking()


def on_press(key):
    if key == button_to_toggle:
        clicker.active = not clicker.active


with MouseListener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    with KeyboardListener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
```